# Can a chaincode in hyperladger have its own certificate for signing transactions? If it can, then how

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

The task is to transfer assets from fabric to another blockchain. For the unlock/lock token contract, it is necessary to come up with a place to store tokens for the time of their blocking. I decided to store them on the client's account. The bottom line is, can I store data on in contact and can I assign a certificate to the contract as a user, for example as in eth? And the contract uses its own certificate when interacting with other contracts.

If there is documentation or code examples, I will be glad of any answers and examples. And then we have already entered a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts in Fabric do not invoke other smart contracts in the way that I *think* you are describing. While a smart contract can use and [invokeChaincode](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.2/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#invokeChaincode) API call to invoke another smart contract, which is done within the scope of the current transaction and can only augment the read/write set of that transaction. If successful, this endorsement / simulation of the transaction is signed by the peer that received the transaction proposal from the client.

In short, smart contracts do not (or at least should not) interact with other smart contracts as if they are a client using their own client identity.

There is some documentation here that might help clarify:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/chaincodenamespace.html#cross-chaincode-access